# Restrict user to one device (logout other devices)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session, webforms

I'm trying to work out how to prevent users from using my webapp from different devices at the same time.

I would like to logout any older sessions when a new user loggs in. However,
I do not wish to query the DB each request.

I have a couple ideas, could anyone explain which would be better, or if there is a better soloution. (Have read about mutex but it seems to be for winforms?)

Approach 1,

> > Store sessionID in the DB on login.
>
> > When a new login occurs go and remove/delete/invalidate the previous SessionID from storage.

Approach 2,

> > Using a static class that holds a list of 'user_session' objects that each contain a LoginID and the SessionID.
>
> > On login update the static class sessionID
>
> > On loading each page, check the sessionID != that of the static class. If it does, logout the user.

Approach 3,

> > Application Cache (same method as above, but replacing static class with app cache)

Approach 4,

> > Using Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute, on login, I could store the UserID + deviceID
>
> > Store this in the web.cache, then on each request, if cache.UserID.DeviceID != that of session, log the user out.

Approach 5,

> > Store device ID in the session
> > On login alter the Session Cookie ID to match that of curent session.
> not sure if this is possible or would cause any unexpected results

Would really apprecaite some opinions on what would be the nicer soloution. Of if there is another way to achieve the said functionality. Cheers!

Comment: What are you using for your session? Cookies, viewstates, or what? How your session is being kept is going to drastically alter what you can/want to do.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of detail, Im using InProc mode to handle sessions. I will update my question to include some more information.

Comment: Unless you put some kind of timed event on the application you aren't going to be able to terminate an InProc session from another machine.  InProc is stored locally on the machine.  How much data are you storing in the session state?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. As far as im aware, the InProc mode stores session data in a memory object in the app worker process (aspnet_wp.exe) in the application domain. Can you think of a solution or give your opinion on some of mine which would allow the session to be terminated once the user tries to access the page? This way being able to terminate a session object remotely isn't an issue. Additionally, I'm not planning to store much in the session object. At most a combination of 10 very short ints and strings

Comment: Personally I prefer data as opposed to storing things on the client.  I would create DB sessions and when a user logs in, disable the old session.  I prefer disable to delete because it provides you a history but you could delete the old session as well.

Comment: Thanks MaCron, I would like to avoid DB sessions due to the delay/wait time it will introduce. Current my user can be logged in and access a page without querying the LoginCredentials table. 100% agree with not deleting but marking as disabled.